# How to redirect sound to loudspeaker from arbitrary app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, settings, audio, loudspeaker

My Samsung Galaxy SIII comes with a front-speaker and a back-loudspeaker. From some applications, such as the Phone app, it is possible to press a software button during a call to redirect the sound to the back-loudspeaker (so that more than one person can hear what the person on the other side of the phone call is saying).

However, I couldn't find the same functionality on the Skype app (or any other videoconferencing or other app).

I would like to know whether there is a system setting somewhere or custom application such that whatever app is running in the foreground, the sound it produces can be somehow redirected to the back-loudspeaker from some external software, so that this can work no matter what app (Phone or other) is running.

Thanks.